# Can I create a subdag with catchup enabled in a dag without catchup?

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

My goal is to schedule jobs with `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator` and `EmrAddStepsOperator`. Namely, I want to create cluster and add add steps for each scheduled day (or hour) starting from specified date. Basically, I want `EmrAddStepsOperator` to be back-filled, but not `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator`. To achieve this I though that I can use sub-dag concept, where parent dag will have disabled catch-up and child dag will have it enabled. I don't want to create EMR cluster for each step.
Is this possible? Are there any other options?

Comment: Catchup=False is set at the Dag level.  
You can try using the same logic as a `ShortCircuitOperator` or a `PythonBranchOperator` for the `ErmCreateJobFlowOperator` task where it will only run if the EMR cluster does not exist

Comment: I am not sure if this solves the problem. I need to add steps to one cluster for the first run and later just a single step for each day. But it seems it can't be done by only using Airflow concept, some additional development.